# Recycler view with Picasso taking more memory

Tags: android, optimization, memory-management, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am using RecyclerView along with Picasso library to display a very long list of images with some text data. I used pagination to load more records and as soon as more records are loaded, Picasso started to download image. The main issue I am facing is when all the non-visible recycler view items along with visible items are kept in memory and it is eating a lot of memory.

I want to release memory for all the non-visible items and as soon as user scrolls, Picasso will start to load image (from network or cache).

Below are sample code which I implemented in my app:

```
/**
 * Adapter class used to display hotel list.
 * Created by gaganpreetsingh on 1/18/2016.
 */
public class HotelListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HotelDetailViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<HotelModel> mModelList;
    private OnRecyclerItemClickListener mListener;

    public HotelListAdapter(Context context, List<HotelModel> modelList,
                            OnRecyclerItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mModelList = modelList;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public HotelDetailViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_hotel_item, parent, false);
        return new HotelDetailViewHolder(view, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HotelDetailViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setItem(mContext, mModelList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mModelList.size();
    }

}
```

Below is the implementation of ViewHolder class:

```
/**
 * View holder class used to display a hotel with
 * location and price.
 * Created by gaganpreetsingh on 1/18/2016.
 */
public class HotelDetailViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 320;
    private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 186;

    private ImageView mImgHotel;
    private TextView mTxtHotelName;
    private TextView mTxtAreaName;
    private TextView mTxtHotelDistance;
    private TextView mTxtPrice;

    private View mRootView;

    private OnRecyclerItemClickListener mListener;

    private int mWidth, mHeight;

    /**
     * Initialize view holder
     *
     * @param itemView to initialize
     */
    public HotelDetailViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecyclerItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        mRootView = itemView;
        mListener = listener;
        mImgHotel = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.img_hotel);
        mTxtHotelName = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_hotel_name);
        mTxtAreaName = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_area_name);
        mTxtHotelDistance = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_hotel_distance);
        mTxtPrice = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
        mRootView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Set the specified hotel details to this
     * view holder
     *
     * @param model to set
     */
    public void setItem(final Context context, final HotelModel model) {

        ViewTreeObserver vto = mImgHotel.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                mImgHotel.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                final int height = mImgHotel.getMeasuredHeight();
                final int width = mImgHotel.getMeasuredWidth();

                // get the target image view width and height
                final int heightDp = AppUtils.getDpFromPx(height, context);
                final int widthDp = AppUtils.getDpFromPx(width, context);

                // if target image has higher size than our max image size,
                // load image with max allowed size.
                if (heightDp > MAX_HEIGHT || widthDp > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    // download resized image
                    PicassoUtils.loadImage(context, model.mImage, mImgHotel, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
                } else {
                    // download resized image
                    PicassoUtils.loadImage(context, model.mImage, mImgHotel, widthDp, heightDp);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });


//        PicassoUtils.loadImage(context, model.mImage, mImgHotel);
        mTxtHotelName.setText(model.mName);
        mTxtAreaName.setText(model.mArea);

       }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null)
            mListener.onClick(mRootView, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

This is the code to load image using Picasso:

```
public static void loadImage(Context context, String url, ImageView imageView,
                                 int width, int height) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(url)
                .error(R.drawable.thumb_photo)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.thumb_photo)
                .resize(width, height)
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

Also, even after loading resized image, I am getting sometime OOM exception as well.

Kindly suggest me some way to release memory for non-visible items and to avoid OOM exception.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, did you figure this out yet?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by downloading the resized image equals to the dimension of the target **ImageView**. To calculate the actual dimensions of the ImageView, I used **ViewTreeObserver**.

Below is sample code of downloading image using **Picasso** in **ViewHolder**:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = mImgHotel.getViewTreeObserver();
            if(vto == null || !vto.isAlive()) return;
            vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    mImgHotel.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    final int height = mImgHotel.getMeasuredHeight();
                    final int width = mImgHotel.getMeasuredWidth();

                    // get the target image view width and height
                    final int heightDp = AppUtils.getDpFromPx(height, context);
                    final int widthDp = AppUtils.getDpFromPx(width, context);

                    // download resized image
                    PicassoUtils.loadImage(context, model.mImage, mImgHotel, widthDp, heightDp);

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sounds like a lot of extra work for every time I load an image with Picasso, you sure this is efficient?

Comment: I solved mostly OOM exceptions by implementing this code. Now I have zero OOM exception using Picasso.

Comment: How do you implement this in an adapter where I am simply calling Picasso.with.load.into ... etc.. Also, if I have 100s of images loading does this make sense to apply to each one - one by one?

Comment: Wherever you are calling Picasso.with.load, write the above piece of code. It will give you the exact dimensions of the target image size to load. As this code is part of ViewHolder, it will apply one-by-one.